# Why isn't only:changes not working in my Gitlab CI yml?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to modify our .gitlab-ci.yml file so that frontend and backend would be deployed only when they have been changed. However, I have not been able accomplish that. Below is main parts of file - it always deploys everything when something is committed.

What I would like to accomplish: 1) only build and deploy frontend when any file has changed in frontend folder 2) only deploy (build not needed) backend when any changes in backend folder.

```
stages:
   - buildfrontend
   - deployfrontend
   - deploybackend
.build-frontend:  
   stage: buildfrontend
   script:
     - ...
   only:
      changes:
         - frontend/**/*     
.deploy-frontend:
   stage: deployfrontend
   script:    
     - ...
   only:
      changes:
         - frontend/**/*     
.deploy-backend:
   stage: deploybackend
   script:
     - ...
   only:
      changes:
         - backend/**/*      
.staging:
  only:
    - master
  variables:
      ...
.production:
   only:
     - production
   variables:
      ...
# STAGING
buildfrontend:staging:
   extends:
      - .build-frontend
      - .staging
deployfrontend to-staging:
   dependencies:
      - buildfrontend:staging
   extends:
      - .deploy-frontend    
      - .staging
deploybackend to-staging:
  extends:
    - .deploy-backend
    - .staging
    
# PRODUCTION      
buildfrontend:production:
   extends:
      - .build-frontend
      - .production
deployfrontend to-production:
   dependencies:
      - buildfrontend:production
   extends:
      - .deploy-frontend    
      - .production
deploybackend to-production:
   extends:
      - .deploy-backend
      - .production
Co
```

Comment: what change do you mean should take place that the deployment should occur subsequently? actually, when the ci job starts there is a new merge request, and similarly, there are some changes that Git lets you commit. Thus, there are some changes somewhere on the project, then there should be a deployment as well. I guess your problem is not well described. add more detail please

Comment: I added a new chapter, hope this clarifies.